# Cloudera: spark Scala: Error: textFile is not part of org.apache.sparkcontext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cloudera

Here is what i did:

```
val sc = new SparkContext
val data1 = sc.textFile("/user/samplecsv.csv")
```

I'm getting the following error:

`textFile is not part of org.apache.sparkcontext`

I'm running Cloudera >> Spark-Shell

Any suggestions please?

Here is the exact error:

```
scala> val data1 = sc.textFile("user/samplecsv.csv") 

<console>:15: error: not found: 

value sc val data1 = sc.textFile("user/samplecsv.csv")
```

Comment: Hello OP, can you please post the entire traceback of the error?

Comment: scala> val data1 = sc.textFile("user/samplecsv.csv")
<console>:15: error: not found: value sc
       val data1 = sc.textFile("user/samplecsv.csv")

Comment: please put the traceback in the question and format it

Comment: Can you check if the file `user/samplecsv.csv` is available in the HDFS or local? Please ensure it to be present in the HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using newer version of `spark 2` or greater, then you don't need to create instance of `SparkContext`. There is already a message displayed when you start `spark-shell` as `Spark session available as 'spark'`

So that you can just do the following

```
scala> val data1 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("user/samplecsv.csv")
data1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = user/samplecsv.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:23
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thank you Ramesh. I'm using Spark 1.6.0 version. I get the following error now: scala> val data1 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("user/samplecsv.csv")
<console>:25: error: not found: value spark
         val data1 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("user/samplecsv.csv")